# Determine when UITableViewCell is deallocated

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, uitableview

I am using core data in my app along with `NSFetchedResultsController` to populate a table. My database has 40k+ entries so the table is rather long. Each table cell has a thumbnail image that is loaded from the web using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage). All works great if I scroll slowly, if I begin to scroll fast within a couple of seconds I get a crash.

*NSZombies isn't showing anything useful.*

I'm guessing that it has to do with `SDWebImage` and loading from the web. The way `SDWebImage` works is by loading the image in the background then setting the downloaded image after it completes downloading (wordy). My thought is that the cells are being deallocated by the `UITableView`, then `SDWebImage` tries to set the image on the deallocated cell. So if I can determine when the `UITableViewCell` is going to be deallocated I can stop the `SDWebImage` downloading process and hopefully fix the issue.

I've tried to add

```
- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"dealloc");
}
```

to catch when the cell is going to be deallocated but I never get anything.

**EDIT**
I have my `-(void)dealloc` method in a subclass UITableViewCell.

**EDIT**
Here is where/how I create the cell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
 static NSString* inventoryCellID = @"InventoryCustomCellID";

 InventoryCustomCell* cell = (InventoryCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:inventoryCellID forIndexPath:indexPath];

 [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

 return cell;
 }


- (void)configureCell:(InventoryCustomCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [cell formatCellWithProduct:[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath] enableAdding:NO];

    cell.openThumbnailButton.tag = indexPath.row;

    [cell.openThumbnailButton addTarget:self action:@selector(presentThumbnailViewWithCell:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

In my custom cell this is the configuration method being called:

```
- (void)formatCellWithProduct:(Product*)product enableAdding:(bool)addingEnabled {

    self.titleLabel.text = product.part_number;
    self.partNumberLabel.text = [[[product.manufacturer allObjects] objectAtIndex:0] name];

    //The SDWebImage UIImageView category method
    [self.thumbImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:product.photo] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"]];
}
```

**EDIT**
Here is the SDWebImage method that downloads the image and sets it.

```
- (void)setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholder options:(SDWebImageOptions)options progress:(SDWebImageDownloaderProgressBlock)progressBlock completed:(SDWebImageCompletedBlock)completedBlock;
{
    [self cancelCurrentImageLoad];

    self.image = placeholder;

    if (url)
    {
        __weak UIImageView *wself = self;
        id<SDWebImageOperation> operation = [SDWebImageManager.sharedManager downloadWithURL:url options:options progress:progressBlock completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished)
        {
            __strong UIImageView *sself = wself;
            if (!sself) return;
            if (image)
            {
                sself.image = image;
                [sself setNeedsLayout];
            }
            if (completedBlock && finished)
            {
                completedBlock(image, error, cacheType);
            }
        }];
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &operationKey, operation, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is instruments telling u?

Comment: It took some digging but found that the completion block on 'setImageWithURL' is being sent to a deallocated instance. So my assumptions were correct, I need to find a way to be notified with the cell is being deallocated by the TableView

Comment: Please post that block. Due to cell reuse you should not count on dealocation of cells

Comment: @vikingosegundo I've updated the download block

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Table views don't tend to allocate and deallocate table view cells much.  Creating cells is expensive, so they get reused when possible, rather than being discarded when they go off screen.

The `UITableViewDelegate` method `-tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` is the better place to update cells to cancel downloads or other no-longer-relevant operations.

It does look like each call to `-setImageWithURL:etc:etc:` is trying to cancel previous downloads for that image view, though.

Comment: don't the cells get deallocated when the tableview is deallocated?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't explain where did you put dealloc method..

I consider you can try to add a category to your viewcontroller for debugging just for test if your cell's deallocation is called (not tu subclass `UITableviewCell`) .

For example:

```
@implementation UITableViewCell(Dealloc)

 - (void)dealloc {
   NSLog(@"dealloc");
   [super dealloc];
 }

@end
```

Do you use ARC? If no than you forgot

```
InventoryCustomCell* cell = (InventoryCustomCell *)[[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:inventoryCellID forIndexPath:indexPath] autorelease];
```

Comment: I've updated my questions but I have the dealloc method in a subclass of UITableViewCell

Comment: Show please cellForRow.. method